# How to get an opening name from a PGN/SAN?

Tags: python, chess

I have a list of chess moves, for example, "e4 c5 Nf3 d6 d4 cxd4 Nxd4 Nf6 Nc3 g6" (I can convert from SAN to PGN or UCI, so don't worry about that). From these moves, I want to get the name of the opening, in this example "Sicilian Defense: Dragon Variation". This functionality is essentially identical to the one you'll find in sites like https://lichess.org/analysis#explorer,  https://www.chess.com/analysis, and https://www.365chess.com/opening.php.

The current approach I have implemented involves making in my case very many requests to the Lichess Masters database via https://explorer.lichess.ovh/masters (see https://lichess.org/api#operation/openingExplorerMaster). However, the problem is that I have to make a very high number of requests, making this approach not viable.

I'm working with Python, so I'd definitely prefer that the solution would be in Python.

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1

Use [pgn-extract](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/)

- Download the eco.pgn
- Download the pgn-extract

Sample command line:

```
pgn-extract.exe -e -omyoutput.pgn mygames.pgn
```

The eco.pgn should be located in the same folder with pgn-extract.exe and your input mygames.pgn.

#### Method 2

Use [pgnhelper](https://pgnhelper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) this is a python package I wrote to add eco (and others) to games in the pgn file.

- pip install pgnhelper
- Download the eco.pgn at from [github repo.](https://github.com/fsmosca/pgnhelper/tree/main/eco) or you can use the eco.pgn from pgn-extract.

Sample command line:

```
pgnhelper addeco --inpgnfn manila1974.pgn --outpgnfn out_manila1974.pgn --inecopgnfn eco.pgn
```

pgnhelper is unique, it saves Two ECO, Two Opening name and 2 Variation names if available.

Example:

```
[ECO "A15"]
[ECOT "D90"]
[Opening "English"]
[OpeningT "Gruenfeld"]
[VariationT "Three knights variation"]
```

The **T** means Transposition. In the first 2 moves or 4 plies it records `[Opening "English"]` and in the next 12 moves it will record `[OpeningT "Gruenfeld"]`. Most softwares I know is only recording opening names by transposition so the `[OpeningT "Gruenfeld"]` in pgnhelper is only `[Opening "Gruenfeld"]` in other software output.

Also I created an [eco github](https://github.com/fsmosca/eco) repo and make some modifications, like changing the QGD opening tag value to Queen's Gambit Declined for clarity to user, supplying missing variation names using the name of player that first make the move based from earliest recorded game, and others. The eco.pgn in github repo supplied for pgnhelper is coming from this repo.

[pgnhelper source in github](https://github.com/fsmosca/pgnhelper)

Comment: Looks good, thanks for the detailed answer. I'll accept once I get a chance to try it

Comment: So how could I run ```addeco``` within a Python program? Also, is pgn-extract only for Windows? I say this because of .exe

Comment: You can use pgnhelper addeco from script see this [example.](https://pgnhelper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#script) On pgn-extract the source code is available so you can compile it to run on linux.

Comment: Alright. Is there a way I could just get a ```get_opening(str)``` function that takes a string that looks like the one in my original question and returns the opening name. I don't have a .pgn file, just a string

Comment: There is a way by converting first your string to pgn format. I have no time for that at the moment. But that is easy to convert to pgn. You can use winboard/xboard for example.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure how I can use these chess GUIs to convert string to PGN

Comment: Also, do I need to convert to PGN? How is it not possible for me to get an opening name from a string of moves?

Comment: Copy your move string, open winboard/xboard, press edit and paste game, then press edit again copy game to clipboard, now open text editor or notepad/wordpad and paste - you will get the pgn.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding me. I'm writing a Python program. I can't manually copy and paste anything.

Comment: From your post `"e4 c5 Nf3 d6 d4 cxd4 Nxd4 Nf6 Nc3 g6" (I can convert from SAN to PGN or UCI, so don't worry about that)` Do you have issues converting it?

Comment: Oh, sorry if that wasn't clear. I meant I can convert to ````"1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 ..."````, not making some PGN file and using that. Anyway, I'm looking into using this: https://github.com/lichess-org/chess-openings. If you can help me with that that would be great.

Comment: Two approaches, we can do a lookup text by text with that lichess opening or build a hash table of positions and compare the hash of the last position of your move text to capture the transposition. You can do this with [python-chess.](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgn.html)